# How to handle multiple domain request on a single server?

Tags: java, apache, nginx, centos, tomcat7

I am using dedicated server. I have hosted different HTML, PHP and wordpress websites on this server those are working perfectly.

Now I want to deploy java web application on this server. So I have installed Apache tomcat server on another port. So now I want to know how I can handle request directly from domain name to tomcat apache server.

Along with this I want to know how I can deploy multiple web applications on single tomcat. I want to know configuration to call different WAR files from tomcat.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Which HTTP server are you using to host your PHP and wordpress websites ?

Comment: On my server Nginx service running on 80 port.

Comment: I think you should alter your question then, the answers will be more specific. I can tell you how to do it with Apache but not Nginx

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache as reverse proxy with the mod_proxy plugin: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Therefore, you can handle all HTTP requests with Apache, specifying which requests shall be redirected to the Java web app in Apache Tomcat - port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to set up a HTTP server (apache, nginx, etc.) as a reverse proxy. Then you can map different domains to different contexts, for example:

```
www.domain.com -> localhost:8080/main/
www.otherdomain.com -> localhost:8080/othermain/ 
subdomain.domain.com -> localhost:8080/anotherwar/
```

For example with Nginx it would be done with a ProxyPass directive. Other HTTP servers have their own respective mechanisms.

Comment: But if you can see all ports are same. I want to call different ports for different domain requests like one is php site another is java.

Comment: Well of course you can use different ports as well. That was just an example on routing 3 domains to 3 different WARs. You can have php or static content serving configured too.